# FasteReport .NET RegisterData

Tags: c#, .net, fastreport

In the report I use `BusinessObjectDataSource`. When I call `RegisterData` I get an error `System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'`.

In the stack trace I have

```
at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Iterator`1.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.GetListFromEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetList()
   at FastReport.Data.BusinessObjectConverter.GetProperties(Column column)
   at FastReport.Data.BusinessObjectConverter.UpdateExistingObjects(Column column)
   at FastReport.Data.BusinessObjectConverter.UpdateExistingObjects(Column column)
   at FastReport.Report.RegisterData(IEnumerable data, String name)
   at Worker.EtrnPrintformGenerator.RegisterData(Report report, PrintformContentItem firstTitle, PrintformContentItem secondTitle, IEnumerable`1 files) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Source\Printforms.Worker.Generation\Printforms.Worker.Generation.Etrn\EtrnPrintformGenerator.cs:line 107
```

But in the sources after call `FastReport.Report.RegisterData(IEnumerable data, String name)`
I have a call `FastReport.Dictionary.RegisterBusinessObject(IEnumerable data, string referenceName, int maxNestingLevel, bool enabled)`

Comment: Convert your list to array i.e data.ToArray(),
It will fix the issue